# Search string in string with wildcard char

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was looking around regex and fnmatch threads but couldn't find similar problem.

User enters some string and I need to find it in string that is in col in dataframe. Strings have N char as a wildcard so N can be one of 3 other letters **B** **W** **C**

```py
'BBBB' in 'BBNBAQWE' = True
```

becouse N transformed into B

```py
'QWER' in 'QNERVFRZ' = True
```

becouse N transformed into W

strings can be diffrent sizes and from my understanding only one N letter can be morphed in that string to fit user request

What im planning is to add True/False value to new col based on output

```py
df['is_present'] = df['strings'].map(lambda x: get_strings(x, user_val))
```

Comment: So you want to check if any of the characters in 'QWER' are in 'QNENVFRZ'? Otherwise, why is it True?

Comment: I've edited my example and added more info about this case, hope that cleared some things out

Comment: That caused only more confusion. Is only 1 letter allowed to be wildcarded? So, we are looking for `xWER`, `QxER`, `QWxR` or `QWEx` where x=any other letter? What did you mean by (B, W, **C**)? To be more precise: if N letters are allowed to wildcarded, than it would be just much easier to look for any of the individual characters (either contains Q, W, E or R). Did you perhaps meant N_th_?

Comment: I've edited once more

Comment: Right, the wildcard was in the string column. Then Patryk has the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to replace every letter of searched pattern allowing 'N' as alternative.

You can switch all the patterns using list comprehension:

```
raw_pattern = 'QWER'
pattern = ''.join(['(?:' + letter + '|N)' for letter in list(raw_pattern)])
#pattern = '(?:Q|N)(?:W|N)(?:E|N)(?:R|N)'
```

Then

```
sentence = 'QNENVFRZ'
re.findall(pattern, sentence)
>>> ['QNEN']
```

If the resulting list is not empty, the pattern was found in the sentence.

Edit:
The question was modified to only accept 'N' if it exchanges 'B', 'W', or 'C'.
Then we would like to create pattern like this:

```
pattern = ''.join(['(?:' + letter + '|N)' if letter in ('B', 'W', 'C') else letter for letter in list(raw_pattern)])
# pattern = 'Q(?:W|N)ER'
```

Of course then the original example does not match, as R was not able to replace N.
We get:

```
re.findall(pattern, sentence)
>>> []
```

We can check whether something was matched comparing to an empty list.

```
re.findall(pattern, sentence) == []
>>> True
```

Comment: I see you added constraint for only a couple letters being changed for N. Then you want to add the (?:X|N) alternative only for X in (B,W,C)

Comment: yeah, can you edit your post to make that constraint, and how can get true/false result out of this

Comment: Btw it's working with no doubt but those two things

Comment: ok i was bit addle-headed when asking about true/false becouse as you said "If the resulting list is not empty, the pattern was found in the sentence." but how to add constraint for those couple of letters